# How to unset a cookie using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cookies

I'm using Apache; I put the following code in .htaccess to unset the Cookie header but it doesn't work:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|jpg|png|jpeg|gif|xml|json|txt|pdf|mov|avi|otf|woff|ico|swf)$">
    RequestHeader unset Cookie
    Header unset Cookie
    Header unset Set-Cookie
</FilesMatch>
```

What is your solution?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. It's highly unlikely that your server will be sending `Set-Cookie` headers for static files in the first place. It sounds like an http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: What Quentin just wrote. Show the text of request + request headers + response headers. That should she more light. You can use the `curl` command-line program for that easily. Adding this information to your question would shed some more light.

Comment: I want to disable Cookies
pls read this article: https://www.keycdn.com/support/how-to-use-cookie-free-domains/
@Quentin

Comment: @user8519380 — Yes? And that article says "Use a different domain". It doesn't say "Try to prevent Cookie headers for specific file extensions". This is because you can't due to the way cookies work.

Comment: author of the article said: the goal is to remove the cookie section and to avoid having the Set-Cookie header present in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Create a subdomain, such as static.yourwebsite.com, which is where you will deliver all your static files from

2 - Point your new subdomain to the /wp-content directory of your WordPress installation. For cPanel users, you will need to update the document root field from public_html/static to public_html/wp-content like the screenshot below.

3 - Edit your wp-config.php file to reflect the following

```
define("WP_CONTENT_URL", "http://static.yourwebsite.com");
define("COOKIE_DOMAIN", "www.yourwebsite.com");
```

4 - Run the following command in your SQL database, this will ensure all post URLs are directed to the new subdomain:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'www.yourwebsite.com/wp-content/','static.yourwebsite.com/')
```

Answer (score 2):

Preventing the server from issuing a `Set-Cookie` response header for specific file types won't stop other file types setting a cookie for the domain. So the browser will still send the cookie and the benefits are lost.

Telling the server to remove a `Cookie` request header before passing it on to the next layer of request processing won't stop the browser from sending it in the first place. So the benefits are lost.

The article you reference in a comment says to serve your static files from a different domain.

Do that. Never write code that sets a cookie for that domain. That's all you need to do.

Comment: I use a different domain، and I'll put the code above but don't work in my server download

Comment: "and I'll put the code above" — Don't do that. All you need to do is use a different domain.

Comment: But my server download sends the cookie.

Comment: Then you need to find the code which sets the cookie and remove it. A server won't set a cookie by default.

Comment: Smells like Google Analytics. I'd guess you have an HTML document on the domain (which you shouldn't, it should just be for images, js, etc) with a GA script tag.